# Concerning the minima of symmetric positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices, analysis, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

In a book I am reading is the following exercise:

> Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TQx+c^Tx+\gamma$ with $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ symmetric and positive definite and $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$. Let further $x^*$ be the global minimum of $f$. Then holds:
>
> $$\frac{1}{2}(x-x^*)^TQ(x-x^*) = f(x) - f(x^*)$$
>
> for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I tried to simply multiply the left side and compare it to the right one, but it did not work out:

$$\frac{1}{2}(x-x^*)^TQ(x-x^*) = f(x) - f(x^*)$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}x^TQx-\frac{1}{2}x^TQx^*-\frac{1}{2}x^{*^T}Qx+\frac{1}{2}x^{*^T}Qx^* = \frac{1}{2}x^TQx + c^Tx- \frac{1}{2}x^{*^T}Qx^{*} - c^Tx^*$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow  -\frac{1}{2}x^TQx^*-\frac{1}{2}x^{*^T}Qx+\frac{1}{2}x^{*^T}Qx^*  = c^Tx- \frac{1}{2}x^{*^T}Qx^{*} - c^Tx^*$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow  -\frac{1}{2}x^TQx^*-\frac{1}{2}x^{*^T}Qx+x^{*^T}Qx^*  = c^Tx-c^Tx^*$$

I think we might need to use that $Q$ is symmetric and positive definite. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Did you try proving it for the case where $n = 1$ using ordinary calculus? That might be instructive.

Comment: The function is quadratic. You may use the method of completing square.

Comment: @JohnHughes: I inserted my attempt for a general $n$ above and I do not see how (for the moment) restricting ourselves to $n=1$ should help here. Could you explain?

Comment: I know you don't see how restricting to $n = 1$ should help; that's why I advised you work out that case, possibly drawing a graph as you do so.

Comment: "Symmetric" is a red herring: for any quadratic form, $u^t B u$, you can replace $B$ by $\frac12(B + B^t)$, which is symmetric, and get the same quadratic form. "Positive definite" is so that a unique global min exists. You really should look at and think about Siong Thye Goh's answer (and should do the $n = 1$ case!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

You might want to use the property that 
$x^*$ satisfies $Qx^*+c=0$ and also use the trick that we can add and subtract the same constant.

Edit:

\begin{align}
&\frac12 x^TQx-\frac12 x^{*T}Qx-\frac12 x^{*T}Qx+\frac12x^{*T}Qx^*\\
&=\frac12x^TQx+c^Tx+\frac12x^{*T}Qx^* \\
&=\frac12x^TQx+c^Tx-\frac12x^{*T}Qx^*+x^{*T}Qx^* \\
&=\frac12x^TQx+c^Tx-\frac12x^{*T}Qx^*-c^Tx^* \\
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see why $Qx^*+c=0$ should be true. Besides, do you mean $Qx^*+cx^* = 0$?

Comment: Try to diferentiate the objective function and that is the first order condition.

Comment: "Besides, do you mean $^∗+^∗=0$?" That doesn't make sense. $Qx$ is an $n$-vector, while $c \cdot x^*$ is a number. $cx^*$ doesn't even make sense in general, because there's no standard product defined for $n$-vectors.